# React Hooks Read CSV From Local Machine

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to rewrite a function to read a CSV file and assign it to state.

The general workflow is to upload a CSV file from local machine, parse it, divide into three different objects and assign it to state.

However, I am getting this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'readable' of undefined

While the class-based component works.

I want to rewrite it using hooks since I would like then to use a global state and be able to access that information in other components.

What am I doing wrong?

This is my functional component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Papa from "papaparse";
import _ from "lodash";

const Upload = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    csvfile: null,
    tShirts: [null],
    felpe: [null]
  });

  function handleChange(event) {
    setState({
      csvfile: event.target.files[0]
    });
  }

  function importCSV(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { csvfile } = state;

    Papa.parse(csvfile, {
      complete: updateData,
      header: true
    });
  }

  function updateData(result) {
    var data = result.data;

    var tshirts = _.map(data, function(o) {
      if (_.includes(o.stampa, "T-Shirt")) return o;
    });
    tshirts = _.without(tshirts, undefined);

    var felpe = _.map(data, function(obj) {
      if (_.includes(obj.stampa, "Felpa")) return obj;
    });

    felpe = _.without(felpe, undefined);

    setState({ tShirts: tshirts, felpe: felpe });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="upload">
        <p>Carica gli ordini</p>
        <input
          className="upload-input"
          type="file"
          name="file"
          placeholder={null}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <p />
        <button onClick={importCSV}>Upload</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Upload;
```

And here the class-based component:

```
import React from "react";
import Papa from "papaparse";
import _ from "lodash";

import TableData from "./TableData";

class Upload extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      csvfile: null,
      tShirts: [null],
      felpe: [null]
    };
    this.updateData = this.updateData.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      csvfile: event.target.files[0]
    });
  };

  importCSV = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { csvfile } = this.state;
    Papa.parse(csvfile, {
      complete: this.updateData,
      header: true
    });
  };

  updateData(result) {
    var data = result.data;

    var tshirts = _.map(data, function(o) {
      if (_.includes(o.stampa, "T-Shirt")) return o;
    });
    tshirts = _.without(tshirts, undefined);

    var felpe = _.map(data, function(obj) {
      if (_.includes(obj.stampa, "Felpa")) return obj;
    });

    felpe = _.without(felpe, undefined);

    this.setState({ tShirts: tshirts, felpe: felpe });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="upload">
          <p>Carica gli ordini</p>
          <input
            className="upload-input"
            type="file"
            ref={input => {
              this.filesInput = input;
            }}
            name="file"
            placeholder={null}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <p />
          <button onClick={this.importCSV}>Upload</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Upload;
```

Comment: Which is the line where this is crashing?

Comment: I'm actually not getting a line, but I think the issue might be due to this: `ref={input => {
              this.filesInput = input;
            }}`

Answer (score 0):

It is not issued with hook. It works perfectly ist time. Once complete, u have to stop import again.

Please check sanbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflowmodal-19i36

// updated method:

```
function importCSV(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { csvfile } = state;

    csvfile &&
      Papa.parse(csvfile, {
        header: true,
        dynamicTyping: true,
        complete: updateData
      });
  }
```

//

```
function updateData(result) {
    setState({
      csvfile: null
    });
```

You can update/refactor accordingly.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Papa from "papaparse";
import _ from "lodash";

const Upload = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    csvfile: null,
    tShirts: [null],
    felpe: [null]
  });

  function handleChange(event) {
    setState({
      csvfile: event.target.files[0]
    });
  }

  function importCSV(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { csvfile } = state;

    csvfile &&
      Papa.parse(csvfile, {
        header: true,
        dynamicTyping: true,
        complete: updateData
      });
  }

  function updateData(result) {
    setState({
      csvfile: null
    });
    var data = result.data;
    console.log(data);
    var tshirts = _.map(data, function(o) {
      if (_.includes(o.stampa, "T-Shirt")) return o;
    });
    tshirts = _.without(tshirts, undefined);

    var felpe = _.map(data, function(obj) {
      if (_.includes(obj.stampa, "Felpa")) return obj;
    });

    felpe = _.without(felpe, undefined);

    setState({ tShirts: tshirts, felpe: felpe });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="upload">
        <p>Carica gli ordini</p>
        <input
          className="upload-input"
          type="file"
          name="file"
          placeholder={null}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <p />
        <button onClick={importCSV}>Upload</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Upload;
```

Comment: Thanks, however I would like it to be a functional component, not a class component

Comment: it is not class componet.. what is u talking abt?? i just use ur example.

Comment: Exactly, I already have a working class-based  component, but I would like to convert it to a functional component using hooks, and this is where the issue comes